# Python Windrose hangs with large dataset, doesn't crash or produce results

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, anaconda, spyder

I am using Anaconda2 Spyder3. When I use `windrose` it works for small datasets but I want to use it for 1 years worth of 10 minute data - 52560 datapoints.

When I run the code below, it just hangs and I never get a result or any error messages.

```
wd = df_A['Yaw_mean']
wd_mod = wd % 360 #convert to 0-360 degrees
wd_mod = wd_mod.values #convert to float64
ws = df_A['ws_mean'].values

ws_subset = ws[0:52560]
wd_subset = wd_mod[0:52560]
ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(wd_subset, ws_subset)
plt.title('Yaw 2016-2017')
plt.savefig(mypath + 'Yaw_Windrose.png')
```

I trialled the same code for smaller subsets of the dataset `ws_subset = ws[0:500]` and it worked:

[image: result from 500 datapoints only]

Are there any alterations I can make to the code without having to alter the input dataset to get this to produce a plot?

Comment: Please try the example shown on the homepage, but use 50000 random samples instead of 500. Is that faster? https://github.com/python-windrose/windrose

Comment: For me, it does not make a difference.

Comment: There is also a Pandas example with a dataframe with the fields speed and direction: https://github.com/python-windrose/windrose/blob/master/samples/example_pandas.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestions above were very helpful. I realised the error was due to some NaN values in the dataset.

resolved with `.dropna()`

```
wd = df_A01['_ScYawPos_mean']
wd = wd.dropna()
wd_mod = wd % 360
wd_mod = wd_mod.values
ws = df_A['ws_mean']
ws= ws.dropna()
```